# Accessing locally hosted url (in PC) from mobile devices

Tags: android, python, flask

I've my backend written in Python hosted in Flask's server. Now, i'm trying to access this localhost from Android and get the JSON response, but i dont know how. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

So i dont know your **localhost** link, but you can try this:

```
http://localhost //This refers to the device where code is running
```

**or**

```
http://127.0.0.1 //This refers to the device where code is running
```

**or**

```
10.0.2.2 //This refers to the computer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the url in your android app to reference your local machine with its IP adress.

For exemple, your server is running on port 5000 so from machine you can call your API with http://localhost:5000. To call it from another machine (as your android phone) you need to call http://{YOUR_IP}:5000

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks for the complement.

Comment: Hey, thnx for the reply.
when i try to access http://localhost:5000 from my PC, it gives me the JSON respone but when i try to access http://<my_ip>:5000 from my Android browser (it's connected to same network), it gives me "Too long to respond" error.
Do i have to configure firewall or something? if yes, can you tell me how?

Comment: Are you sure that you got the good IP adress ? You need the private IP of your PC not the public adress.

Comment: Yeah, I used ipv4 address from ipconfig and that gave me "too long to respond" error

Comment: Could you try to install a terminal on your phone and ping your PC adress ?

Comment: Yes, i can ping my private ip from android.

Comment: That&#39;s weird... Can you get the json reponse from your Android browser ?

Comment: Hey, when i changed the hosting address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, i was able to get the JSON response. I wasnt able to do that through 127.0.0.1 even when i disabled my firewalls. Strange!
Is there any security concerns on hosting it on 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Not that I know but I'm not very confortable with windows.